# an exception while running dockerized Django project locally which is hosted on google cloud run

Tags: python, django, docker, google-cloud-run, geodjango

I have cloned a dockerized GeoDjango project and want to run it locally which is hosted on google cloud run. I have also tried to run the project without docker by running `python manage.py runserver` but all in vain.

This is the exception error which is occurring

```
Exception: No local .env or GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT detected. No secrets were found.
```

I created the image by using this command:

```
docker build . -t your_image_name
```

when I run this command:

```
docker run -p 9090:8080 -e PORT=8080 my_image_name
```

It gives the error traceback given below.

Error traceback:

```
[2022-07-24 08:16:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-07-24 08:16:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[2022-07-24 08:16:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2022-07-24 08:16:45 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[2022-07-24 08:16:49 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/whg/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/whg/settings.py", line 55, in <module>
    raise Exception("No local .env or GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT detected. No secrets found.")
Exception: No local .env or GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT detected. No secrets found.
[2022-07-24 08:16:49 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
[2022-07-24 08:16:50 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2022-07-24 08:16:50 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

my `settings.py` for getting .env file which is located in my root directory:

```
env_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")

# Attempt to load the Project ID into the environment, safely failing on error.
try:
    _, os.environ["GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"] = google.auth.default()
    print("\n 1 Google cloud project \n")
except google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError:
    pass

if os.path.isfile(env_file):
    # Use a local secret file, if provided

    env.read_env(env_file)
# [START_EXCLUDE]
elif os.getenv("TRAMPOLINE_CI", None):
    # Create local settings if running with CI, for unit testing

    placeholder = (
        f"SECRET_KEY=a\n"
        "GS_BUCKET_NAME=None\n"
        f"DATABASE_URL=sqlite://{os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')}"
    )
    env.read_env(io.StringIO(placeholder))
# [END_EXCLUDE]
elif os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT", None):
    # Pull secrets from Secret Manager
    project_id = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT")

    client = sm.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    settings_name = os.environ.get("SETTINGS_NAME", "django_settings")
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{settings_name}/versions/latest"
    payload = client.access_secret_version(name=name).payload.data.decode("UTF-8")

    env.read_env(io.StringIO(payload))
else:
    raise Exception("No local .env or GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT detected. No secrets found.")
```

It is my very first experience running Django project locally which is hosted on google cloud run on a remote server and dockerized as well.

Answer (score 0):

This line that contains `_, os.environ["GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"] = google.auth.default()` declares that your application is designed to use `ADC` (Google Application Default Credentials). When running in Cloud Run, `ADC` is already set up for an application.

The solution is to install the cloud SDK, set up the CLI, and choose your auth method (user login, service account, etc).

Start here and set up your environment:

[Install the gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install)

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your valuable answer. I have installed the Cloud SDK and set up the CLI for the google cloud run project. now, it is giving the same issue again.

Comment: NOTE: it is also initialized. I am also logged in on cloud run from my developer gmail. and selected the required project from CLI choosing a number.

Comment: @djangodeveloper  Did you run this command `gcloud config set project REPACE_WITH_YOUR_PROJECT_ID`?

Comment: no. I just installed and connected my cloud run project via CLI commands provided by google itself

Comment: @djangodeveloper - What happens when you do?

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply as it was night here

Comment: when I ran the following command: `gcloud config set project REPACE_WITH_YOUR_PROJECT_ID`, the command line says : `Updated property [core/project]`.

Comment: and after that, when I type `docker run -p 9090:8080 -e PORT=8080 my_docker_image` : it throws the same error. that was discussed in the question. means it is still not finding the project id

Comment: I am feeling sorry, as I am taking your time.

Comment: @djangodeveloper Are these errors coming from an application running on your desktop or inside the Docker container? The container is isolated from your desktop environment. That means you will need to set up ADC inside the container. The easiest is to use a service account.

Comment: when I run the commands inside the dockerized container, it gives this error. but when I run it without docker, it was giving the issue related GDAL, although it is working on local machine without docker and cloud run. but still not sure how to run it with cloud run?

Comment: so should I repeat the same commands inside the docker image?

Comment: @djangodeveloper Please check on the article https://medium.com/@rahulxsharma/django-on-google-cloud-run-3f2f93ae0917